# Having Trouble Parsing JSON Data In Netbeans

Tags: java, json, netbeans

(I am new to JSON data so my terminology may not be on point)
(If you do not understand my question please comment why)
I am taking in JSON data from an API and storing it in a .json file. The data that is coming is formatted like this:

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "trails": [
    {
      "summary": "Grand, scenic views, begins fast \u0026 smooth, becomes very technical, epic singletrack.",
      "imgSmallMed": "https://cdn-files.apstatic.com/mtb/7000093_smallMed_1554393017.jpg",
      "latitude": 32.7071,
      "length": 10.3,
      "stars": 4.5,
      "type": "Ride",
      "starVotes": 2,
      "conditionDate": "1970-01-01 00:00:00",
      "difficulty": "black",
      "descent": -6257,
      "high": 9356,
      "ascent": 203,
      "conditionStatus": "Unknown",
      "low": 3303,
      "name": "Ash Creek",
      "location": "Swift Trail Junction, Arizona",
      "id": 7000218,
      "imgSqSmall": "https://cdn-files.apstatic.com/mtb/7000093_sqsmall_1554393017.jpg",
      "longitude": -109.9103
    },
    {
      "summary": "Roadside access and scenic views. Begins slow and smooth, then gets techy, followed by an adrenaline-pumping downhill!",
      "imgSmallMed": "",
      "latitude": 32.6626,
      "length": 3.1,
      "stars": 4,
      "type": "Ride",
      "starVotes": 1,
      "url": "https://www.mtbproject.com/trail/7050395/noon-creek-loop",
      "imgSmall": "",
      "imgMedium": "",
      "conditionDate": "1970-01-01 00:00:00",
      "difficulty": "black",
      "descent": -604,
      "high": 5711,
      "ascent": 585,
      "conditionStatus": "Unknown",
      "low": 5184,
      "name": "Noon Creek Loop",
      "location": "Swift Trail Junction, Arizona",
      "id": 7050395,
      "imgSqSmall": "",
      "longitude": -109.8013
    },
    {
      "summary": "Two short single tracks connected by old jeep trails with two excellent view points.",
      "imgSmallMed": "https://cdn-files.apstatic.com/mtb/7011629_smallMed_1554839996.jpg",
      "latitude": 32.6792,
      "length": 10.3,
      "stars": 3.5,
      "type": "Ride",
      "starVotes": 4,
      "conditionDate": "1970-01-01 00:00:00",
      "difficulty": "blue",
      "descent": -1127,
      "high": 9442,
      "ascent": 1130,
      "conditionStatus": "Unknown",
      "low": 8727,
      "name": "Grant Hill and Cunningham Trails",
      "location": "Swift Trail Junction, Arizona",
      "id": 3963377,
      "imgSqSmall": "https://cdn-files.apstatic.com/mtb/7011629_sqsmall_1554839996.jpg",
      "longitude": -109.8942
    }
  ]
}
```

I have been trying to sort through this data and just get the name, latitude, longitude, and difficulty of each of the objects. 
What I want to be printed out or stored in a .json file is the value of "name", "difficulty", "latitude", and "longitude" for each of the objects.

So what I want to happen is I want to go through each object in "trails" and get the value of "name", "difficulty", "latitude", and "longitude" and store those values in a txt file. So there needs to be a loop where the code cycles through each object in "trails" and grabs and stores the values of "name", "difficulty", "latitude", and "longitude". But what is happening is all the values in each object in "trails" (ex. "summary", "length", "stars") are being stored on one line (per each object) in the txt file or just printed out as one line to the console. I need to ignore some of those values (ex. ignore "summary") and just get "name", "difficulty", "latitude", and "longitude". As well as be able to have "name", "difficulty", "latitude", and "longitude" stored on separate lines. (I hope this is clear)
This is what should be stored from the data above:

```
"latitude": 32.7071,
"difficulty": "black",    
"name": "Ash Creek",
"longitude": -109.9103
"latitude": 32.6626,
"difficulty": "black",
"name": "Noon Creek Loop",
"longitude": -109.8013
"latitude": 32.6792,
"difficulty": "blue",
"name": "Grant Hill and Cunningham Trails",
"longitude": -109.8942
```

I can separate each object but I can not sort through each object and get specific values. This is the code that I have been working on:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class ReadJSON
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try
        {
            Object object = parser.parse(new FileReader("trails6copy.json"));
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)object;
            JSONArray trails = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("trails");
            String sum = (String) trails.get(0);
            System.out.println(sum);
            for(Object trail : trails)
            {
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("trailSorter.txt",false);
                    writer.write(trail.toString());
                writer.close();     
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fee)
        {
            fe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

PLEASE HELP!!! I have been stuck on this for a week!!

Answer (score 2):

What are you doing is to convert all of the object to a String, that why you get that result.

You need to change the foreach you're doing.
I recommend to use JSONObject instead of Object to access the elements.

```
for(JSONObject trail : trails)
        {
            String line = "Name: " + trail.get("name") + "Difficulty: " + trail.get("difficulty"); //Add all the elements you want
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("trailSorter.txt",false);
                writer.write(trail.toString());
            writer.close();     
        }
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I had to change the code a little bit but you gave me a starting point. Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code. Thank you, Carlos Estrada!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class ReadJSONExample
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try
        {
            Object object = parser.parse(new FileReader("trails6copy.json"));


            //convert Object to JSONObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)object;
            JSONArray trails = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("trails");
            //String sum = (String) trails.get(0);
            //System.out.println(sum);
            for (Iterator it = trails.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                JSONObject trail = (JSONObject) it.next();
                String line = "Name: " + trail.get("name") + "Difficulty: " + trail.get("difficulty"); //Add all the elements you want
                try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("trailSorter.txt",false)) {
                    writer.write(line.toString());
                }     
            }


        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fe)
        {
            fe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```